# Export raster from geodatabase to tif failure in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, export, geotiff-tiff

I have a raster in a file geodatabase and I am trying to export it out of the gdb to tif format.  Every time I try it Arc produces a tif file that no other programs seem to be able to read.

I've tried doing it with the Copy to Raster GP tool, right click on raster in TOC -> export data, and the Raster To Other Format tool.  The tools run successfully per Arc, and ArcMap can read the resulting raster.  But when I try to load in into AutoCAD Map3D 2017 (via MAPIINSERT or the Map Workspace connection manager) I get the message:

> (file path) was not found or is not valid

Photoshop CS5.1 just throws an error window saying:

> could not complete request because it is not right kind of document

File path is less than 132 characters & pixel depth/type is FLOAT 32 (it doesn't seem to mater if I specify FLOAT 32 or not when I run the export tools)

Comment: In my experience, FGDB rasters have some compatibility issues. Do try exporting it as an ESRI grid first, then from the grid export it into a tif, and see if that works.